# Java loop control

Tags: java, nested-loops, continue

This algorithm is made to compare the route of the First ship to a plenty of other ships.I have to tell which ships  do not cross the path of the First one.I imagined to solve this by telling which ships do not have common coordinates with the First ship's route in a coordinate system.

The **first loop** count the other ships which i compare to the first one.

The **second loop** counts each movements (from which the path of the ships built up) of the actual ship (which is compared to the First). Each movement has 2 coordinates.

The **third loop** should compare the coords of the other ships(given by the second loop) TO the First Ship.

In the third loop i gave a condition: if both coordinates equal the First ship's coords of its path, the whole damn thing should be started again from the first loop, which means the other ships count. (**continue** keyword)

If the second loop can ever end, i add the winner ship's index to my ArrayList 'goodships'.

---

**The problem:** No ships are added to the ArrayList, though my input coordinates definitely have different from the First ships's coords.

---

```
    ArrayList<Integer> goodships = new ArrayList<>();

    first: for (int i = 1; i < control.size(); i++) {

        char[] actdirections = control.get(i).toCharArray();
        int[] actualship = new int[2];

        second: for (int j = 0; j < actdirections.length; j++) {
            if (actdirections[j] == 'E') {
                actualship[0]--;
            } else if (actdirections[j] == 'D') {
                actualship[0]++;
            } else if (actdirections[j] == 'N') {
                actualship[1]--;
            } else if (actdirections[j] == 'K') {
                actualship[1]++;
            }
            third: for (int x = 0; x < firstship.length; x++) {
                if ((actualship[0] == firstship[x][0])
                        && (actualship[1] == firstship[x][1])) {
                    continue first;
                }
            }
        }
        goodships.add(i);
    }
```

Comment: What values do you expect in array `actualship`? Also why you have set `i = 1` in the first loop? Are you sure that array `actdirections` always have values in upper case `(E/D/N/K)`?

Comment: What happens in the debugger? Does the logic flow as you expect?

Comment: Yes try using debugger or simple use `System.out.println("something")` at various points and try to debug

Comment: I sat i = 1 because i dont want to count the firstship's coords which is control.get(0) Yes, the values are correct as well. 'actualship' is dynamic and always changes by +1 or -1, depends on the next command i imported.

Comment: What is 'firstship'? and "control"?

Comment: "Firstship" is a twodimensional array which containes all of the first ships coordinates, from the first movement to the last.

Comment: "Control" is an arraylist, which containes lines of characters, each line represents each ships movements from their first movement to the last.

Comment: Control consist of: E,N,D,K each of them means a step to the represented directions.

Comment: Please provide a small example input.

Comment: While I'm not sure i follow your code. This line `int[] actualship = new int[2];` seems suspicious. Are you sure thats what you want?

Comment: how have you initialised `control` and `firstship` variables?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a new import file, tested the program with every scenario and it seems to be working. The previous import file contained 120+ different ships with different coordinates, it happaned to not have 2 ships with completely different route. Sorry for your time.

However, im curious if this solution is memory efficient. Or theres's a better way?